# Conflict between subscript and superscript under summation

Tags: math-mode, subscripts, superscripts

I would like the subscript of my sum to look better:

```
$$
\sum_{d \mid p_j^{m_j}} f(d)
$$
```

creates the output

[image]

but i would like the exponent m_j to be further down and closer p_j.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Off-topic: Please see the posting [Why is `\[ ... \]` preferable to `$$ ... $$`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/5001) for an in-depth discussion of why one shouldn't use `$$` to initiate and terminate display math mode in LaTeX documents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd like to suggest that you `\smash` the subscript term `j` in `p_j`. Alternatively, you could `\smash` the `j` subscript term in `m_j`. Optionally, to remove any ambiguity as to where `j` in `p_j` belongs, snug it up to the `p` term via a `\!` ("negative thinspace") directive.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for \smash[t] macro
\begin{document}
\[
\sum_{d \mid p_{j}^{m_j}} 
\quad\mbox{vs.}\quad
\sum_{d \mid p_{\smash[t]{\!j}}^{m_j}} 
\quad\mbox{vs.}\quad
\sum_{d \mid p_{\!j}^{m_{\smash{j}}}}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the commands `\lef`t and `\right` to force something before and after a certain text. If you just want to use something to one side, use `.` to avoid the unwanted side.

```
\documentclass{article}
   
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{equation}
\sum_{\left.{d}\right|_{p_j}^{m_j}}f(d)
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Here you go!

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but `{p_j}` should *not* be placed on a line below `d`. Your notation also fails to treat `m_j` as a modifier of `p_j`.

Comment: Very sorry, I misread it.